# How to set up OrientDB PyOrient OGM with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orientdb, pyorient

I am having difficulties in connecting Django with Orientdb PyOrient OGM.

I have set the following connection strings and initialisation methods in my settings.py file in Django.

```
# PYORIENT DB SETTINGS
DJANGORIENT_SETTINGS = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '2480',
    'username': 'xxxx',
    'password': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'name': 'authdb'
}

from pyorient.ogm import declarative
Node = declarative.declarative_node()
Relationship = declarative.declarative_relationship()
```

but I am unable to connect to the database via my models.py file

```
from pyorient.ogm.property import *
from .settings import Node

class Car(Node):
    registration = String(unique=True)
    colour = String()
```

Any advice on how to connect the two technologies?

Comment: Hi @Tommyk, which version of OrientDB and Django you use?

Comment: Did you try any of these?
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/PyOrient-Client.html
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/PyOrient-Client-DB-Create.html
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/PyOrient-Client-DB-Open.html
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/PyOrient-OGM-Connection.html